# fprintf randomly produces strange results

Tags: c, logging, printf

I have this piece of code which logs a memory cache to a file:

```
void cache_dump(const int signal) {
    rewind(cache_file); // this is ok, because the cache will never shrink

    unsigned int n;

    for (n = 0; n < cache_size; n++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cache[n].device, device_buffer, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cache[n].remote.sin_addr, remote_buffer, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

        fprintf(cache_file, "%-15s %-15s %-5u %-lu\n", device_buffer, remote_buffer, ntohs(cache[n].remote.sin_port), cache[n].last_seen);
    }
}
```

The struct in cache looks like so:

```
struct cache_entry {
    struct in_addr device;
    struct sockaddr_in remote;
    unsigned long last_seen;
};
```

**Additional info**:

- `device_buffer` and `remote_buffer` are `char[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]` so sufficiently big for an ipv4 address
- the code is **NOT** multithreaded
- other processes access the file in read only mode - this code is the only one with write privileges

**Strange results**

Randomly, the result file will be corrupted, like so:

```
10.13.14.247   10.12.19.240   31337 1472552078
10.13.14.248   10.12.11.244   31337 1472552079
10.13.14.249   10.12.11.237   313310.108.16.151   10.230.16.102   31337 1469798419
10.13.28.1     10.12.26.148   31337 1472551983
10.13.28.58    10.12.127.241  31337 1472552008
```

So, one line would abruptly break (without the new line) and merge with the next one. This happens very rarely, but still. It seems to be related to high system loads, but that's a guess after looking at `htop`.

Has anyone ever encountered such strange behaviour?

**UPDATE**

The cache file is opened like this:

```
cache_fd = open(logpath, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH); // open for writing, empty, create if does not exist, set 444 rights

if (cache_fd == -1)
    die("Failed to open cache file for writing!");

cache_file = fdopen(cache_fd, "w");

if (cache_file == NULL)
    die("Failed to open cache file descriptor for writing!");
```

Comment: I see the variable named `signal`. Is there a signal handler printing to the file also?

Comment: is cache_file buffered? Un-buffered? Could you share the file open code?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart this is connected to a signal handler for a per-request use, but currently it is not used that way - it gets periodically executed from the mail loop

Comment: @LPs see the update please

Comment: Why are you mixing low-level file descriptor and `FILE*` usage? I suspect a bad interaction between your use of the two. Have a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/31687964/119527

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I wanted more fine grained control over file creation (especially setting read only privileges for others) - the descriptor is not used anywhere else in the code - this is the only time I'm mixing the two

Comment: Okay, that's fine then.

Comment: Is it possible that you sometimes have two instances of the writer process running at the same time?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is not possible - I've triple checked that :)

Comment: Try to put a mutex, or a guard of any type and see if sometimes the guard fails.

Comment: BTW what is the frequency of main loop calling that func?

Comment: @LPs - max 1 per minute. I don't know if mutex would help, since the code is single-thread. Additionally, the code isn't executed by a timer with a select - it is a simple systime difference check in the main loop iteration

Comment: The code you present does not by itself explain the behavior you describe.  If (1) system-wide, nothing modifies the file except a single thread at a time executing the code you present, and (2) the writing process does not manipulate its open file description for the file except via the code you present, then the result you describe would characterize a bug in the underlying system.  I think it's more likely, however, that either (1) or (2) does not actually hold.

Comment: Is there a console? With a simple `printf` the behavior is the same? And try to add a timestamp for each `fprintf` and if the difference is not 1 minute....

Comment: @JohnBollinger I totally agree with both points, and I would have not written here if iIwould not check those 2 things twice :) This is a bizzare error - which happens rarely and randomly :/ I'm starting to suspect hardware corruption...

Comment: @LPs - can't check this with `printf` there are thousands of entires, and this unfortunately happens only on production server so there is no space to experiment on :/

Comment: @er453r, if you insist that my (1) and (2) both *do* hold, then I don't see how we can help you, at least not with only the information provided.

Comment: Are you running low on disk space? Writes can fail, and the program isn't checking the return value from fprintf.

Comment: Step 1: Check the return value for `fprintf()`. If `fprintf()` detected a problem it _should_ return `EOF`.  2) Replace `rewind()` with `fseek()` and check its return value too.  3) After the `fprintf()` perform a `fflush()` and check its return value - at least as part of debugging.  4) Rather than state "device_buffer and remote_buffer are char[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] so sufficiently big for an ipv4 address", post that code that supports that as that is best evidence.  Post the code that shows the type of `cache[n].last_seen`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thats the way, I will add error handling to fprintf and report back

Comment: @chux I will add the 1, 2 and 3 for full error handling - as for 4 - that exactly the code as stated in the question, buffers are `char[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]` (46), and `last_seen` is `unsigned long` - no tricks here :)

Comment: Just looking for potential holes: Idea that _may_ help.  Undefined behavior sometimes invoke very strange such as printing a character array that is not null character terminated. Using `"%-15.46s %-15.46s...` to limit printing should the arrays lack a null character.  Of course UB in unposted code is a real possibility.

Comment: Curious, does bad output "10.13.14.249   10.12.11.237   313310.108.16.151   10.230.16.102   31337 1469798419"  contain any hidden control characters like `'\r'` or `'\t`?

Comment: 2 more ideas: 1) `rewind()` does not erase the file's content, so what is seen _could_ be a result of current and previous `()` calls .  Suggest first printing `cache_size`.  2) Insure `cache_size` does not exceed what `cache[]` can handle.